# An integral problem to compute $\iint_{y\ge x^2+1} \frac{1}{x^4+y^2}\,dx\,dy.$

Tags: integration, analysis

How to compute $$\iint_{y\ge x^2+1} \frac{1}{x^4+y^2}\,dx\,dy.$$ I've tried using the transformation $x = \sqrt{r\cos(\theta)},y=r\sin(\theta)$. But I found it hard to compute the integral with $\theta$.

Comment: Did you try to integrate over $y$ first?

Answer (score 3):

@metamorphy's tip is to first evaluate$$\begin{align}\int_{x^2+1}^\infty\frac{dy}{x^4+y^2}&=[x^{-2}\arctan(yx^{-2})]_{x^2+1}^\infty\\&=x^{-2}(\tfrac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(1+x^{-2})),\end{align}$$so the double integral is$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{-2}(\tfrac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(1+x^{-2}))dx&=\int_0^\infty x^{-2}(\pi-2\arctan(1+x^{-2}))dx\\&\stackrel{z=1/x}{=}\int_0^\infty(\pi-2\arctan(1+z^2))dz\\&=\left[\pi z-2z\arctan(1+z^2)+{2}^{\frac54}\sum_\pm e^{\pm3\pi i/8}\arctan\frac{ze^{\pm\pi i/8}}{{2}^{\frac14}}\right]_0^\infty\\&=\sqrt{2(\sqrt{2}-1)}\pi.\end{align}$$